# Formatting a html input box to numeric input only - Correctly formating the minus character

Tags: javascript, html, input, user-input

I'm trying to format a html text input box so that it only accepts numeric values (using javascript). This means the input can only be a digit, a minus or a dot/comma (a comma gets replaced with a dot anyway).

The thing is, a minus must be prevented if it is not the first character of the string. Ex: "-30" is a valid input, but "80----20" is not. Does anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");

function inputHandle(event, object){

 var input = document.getElementById("value");
 var comma = false;

 for (i=0; i<input.value.length; i++) {
     var array = input.value;

     if (input.value[i] == ".") {
      comma = true;
     }
    }

 if ((event.keyCode == 13) && (Number(input.value) < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)) {
  object.innerHTML = Number(input.value);
 }

    if ((event.charCode == 44) && (comma == false)) {
     input.value = input.value + ".";
     event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!((/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/.test(event.key) == true)
    || (((event.charCode == 118) || (event.charCode == 99) || (event.charCode == 97)) && (event.ctrlKey))
    || (event.keyCode == 8)
    || (event.keyCode == 46)
    || (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 40)
    )) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ((event.charCode == 46) && (comma == true)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>

<input type='text' onkeypress='inputHandle(event, div)' accept-charset='ISO-8859-1' id='value' name='coefficientvalue' placeholder='Enter a value...'>
```

Comment: Why not simply `<input type="number" ... />` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)?

Comment: @Andreas I believe `<input type="number" ... />` does not accepts decimal numbers...

Comment: Don't believe, just test it: https://jsfiddle.net/oy7vfofx/ (you will have to adjust the `step` attribute to match the allowed/accepted precision)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need a input[type="text"] I think a regular expression is the best you could use. The following Regex should work:

```
/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/
```

You could check the input value on each input-event with this regex like the following:

```
/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/.test(input.value)
```

Otherwise you should use `type="number"` for your input element, like Andreas commented.

After testing the input you should use `parseFloat` to normalize the input, since the Regex would allow inputs like ".2" or "2.".

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, gerex is much more appropriate (I'm not experienced at all in this, that's why I didn't used it), but unfortunately this doesn't fix my issue. First of all, this regex code is not enough, as besides all digits, the minus and the dot character I also need to include all arrows, the delete and the backspace keys. If you could help me figure the regex syntax of this out I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, as I'm trying to prevent the user from typing unwanted characters into the input box instead of validating the input, I actually need to do `/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/.test(event.key)` and prevent the key event if it returns false. Besides that, I can still place multiple minus characters anywhere I want, so I don't see the point of this... Thanks for the help anyway! I've updated the code snippet replacing all that weird `charcCode <= 35` stuff whith regex notation (at least everything I was able to).

Comment: Could you check my CodePen and check if this is the wanted behaviour? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KojmBx 
Im using the "input"-event to validate the complete input string.

Comment: Pretty elegant solution!